# Cocoa error (256)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

I am using core data in my source-code for data persistence. The framework is being used to persist some preferences in my RSS feed app across different devices all linked to the same iCloud account.

```
    -(id)init{
       if (self= [super init]) {
           model= [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];

           NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc= [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:model];

              NSError *error= nil;
              NSString *dbPath=[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
             [dbPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"feed.db"];
              NSLog(@"%@",dbPath);
              NSURL *dbURL= [NSURL fileURLWithPath:dbPath];

            if (![psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:dbURL options:nil error:&error]) {
               [NSException raise:@"Open failed" format:@"Reason: %@",[error localizedDescription]];
             }

             context= [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
             [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:psc];

             [context setUndoManager:nil];
          }
          return self;
    }
```

Error in the console—

```
  2015-05-08 23:15:03.963 Nerdfeed4[1023:22906] CoreData: error: -     addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:(null) 

  URL:file:///Users/Rahul/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/28EDC37B-E3AA-  442F-A1B1-72AD385563D5/data/Containers/Data/Application/BF11CCC0-0B2C-4537-BAB6-  E27E2C84CC4C/Documents/ options:(null) ... returned error Error    Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa     error 256.)"

    UserInfo=0x7a092c70 {NSUnderlyingException=unable to open database   file,      

    NSSQLiteErrorDomain=14} with userInfo dictionary {
    NSSQLiteErrorDomain = 14;
    NSUnderlyingException = "unable to open database file";
  }
  2015-05-08 23:15:03.977 Nerdfeed4[1023:22906] *** Terminating app due to  uncaught exception 'Open failed', reason: 'Reason: The operation couldn’t be   completed. (Cocoa error 256.)
```

Clearly from the error,one can figure out that the execution stops at the "if(![psc addPersistentStoreWithType:.. configuration:.. URL:.. options:..error]) " because this message returns 0 for the exception to be thrown.  How do i resolve this.. Pls assist. I do a clean build each time before the project is run.

Comment: if that helps "Cocoa error 256" is `NSFileReadUnknownError = 256,                                           // Read error (reason unknown)` .

Comment: Have you made any changes to your Managed Object Model recently?

Comment: @RASS  What sort of changes do u mean?

Comment: I mean any changes at all. A new attribute, entity, changed attribute name, type. The works.

Comment: OK I'm about to be offline for a while, but one possible cause for this error is that you've changed the model: [Changing the Schema Makes a Model Incompatible With Old Stores](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdUsingMOM.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `stringByAppendingPathComponent` method does not mutate the receiver (`dbPath`), it returns the new value, so this line:

```
         [dbPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"feed.db"];
```

does nothing.  You need to assign the return value to a new path string, and use that in the subsequent code:

```
    NSString *newPath = [dbPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"feed.db"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete the app from the simulator and restart. As was pointed out by other posters, you most likely change the database schema and now have an incompatible database file.